# how get unique id ios device with Game Center

Tags: ios, objective-c, unique, game-center

Please help.
I cant get any unique id from ios device, all ids is changing at the time;
I think with Game Ceneter it is posible but how?

Comment: are you using game center? or you just want an unique identifier?

Comment: in objective c I want an any unique identifier from device

Comment: Use UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor

Comment: It is not constant! it is changing at the time.

Comment: It's constant once the app is in the store, it changes when you are developing and you delete the app and reinstall

Answer (score 0):

You should use OpenUDID.

https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID

It gives you an ID that will be unique 99.99% of the time, without a web based management.